# Search and remove a line of text from HTML file

Tags: html, vbscript, scripting, cmd

I'm trying to find a script that searches my index.html file and removes a line of text in it. We currently have setup a intranet site that people can go on and add items they have for sale (thanks to stackoverflow with help on this!).

I have searched everywhere for a file that will do this but I just can't get it to work....

I want it to search my index.html file for a line with a specific text (using a inputbox) and remove that whole line. It's a simple line of HTML it'll be removing, just a date/time and link so 1 line removal should cover it.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

If this can be done through cmd I'd be happy with that as well, I just can't find something that will do what I need...

**Update:**
This code searches index.html for the text you type in cmd and creates a index2.html, deletes index.html, renames index2.html to index.html then deletes the item html page as well out of the folder.

```
@echo off  
ECHO.  
ECHO.  
ECHO.  
ECHO Type item to remove  
set /p item=  
Type "\\server\public\employee resources\bulletin\items\index.html" | findstr /I /V /C:"%item%" >>"\\server\public\employee resources\bulletin\items\index2.html"  


del "\\server\public\employee resources\bulletin\items\index.html"  
rename "\\server\public\employee resources\bulletin\items\index2.html" "index.html"  

del "\\server\public\employee resources\bulletin\items\%item%.html"
```

Comment: SO is neither a script writing, nor a script recommendation service. If you expect people on SO to help you need to show what you have tried and explain how the results were different from what you expected.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far. We can help improve your code to achieve what you are looking at. It can be simply a javascript with RegEx or something else. But we need to know what you have tried already and what are you proficient in.

Comment: just read your edit. Idea: you could check the input and echo an error, if the item does not exist. Something like: `if not exist "\\server.....\%item%.html echo This Item does not exist & goto input`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple program that open your file and modify what you need.
The problem is: your webserver and your editing program doesn't share the same environment, so you'll need a common place where your webserver could write the input box content and your editing program could read that info, tipically a database.

Anyway your question sounds a little bit confusing. Do you really need this? There are a lot of more powerfull way to dinamically build/edit a page.

Comment: Well I can go in and delete the line manually, but some people in my department that will also be editing the items aren't code savvy. So I'm trying to make it as easy as possible for them so it doesn't get messed up.

Comment: you may have a look at `find /?` and `findstr /?`. Especially take a look at the parameter `/v`.

Comment: I don't tell about remove line manually!
I talk about dinamically build the page, reading the line that you want to show from a DB table (so you could remove from the DB the line that you won't show).

Comment: Got it, updated the initial post with the working code. Thanks again. You guys are awesome!